# Is there a way to mimic symlink behavior with an apache configuration?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to mimic symlink behavior with an apache configuration?

For example, from `/var/www/someFolder/` I need to reference files in `/var/www/anotherFolder/` but do it without using relative paths (because I'm using subdomains) or absolute paths.

*Note: Symlinks work but they don't deploy well from git and from my demo site.  I would think an apache configuration is much more deployable then dozens of symlinks*

Is there a way?  With htaccess?  With ServerAlias?  etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then following code in your .htaccess should work fine:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^someFolder/(.*)$ anotherFolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

This way a URI of `http://domain.com/somefolder` will be internally referencing files from `/anotherFolder/` folder thus giving you an effect of symlink without creating an actual symlink.

Comment: Yes it should work with sub domains assuming they also have `someFolder` as DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: This worked for me for the javascript and css but not the php

Comment: Made a minor correction, can you try again. And pls report issues in some details like what error you see? Are you seeing 404 page for php requests? If you still get 404 then I would suggest for testing purpose having above rule like this: RewriteRule ^someFolder/(.*)$ anotherFolder/$1 [L,NC,R] and see what URL you get in your browser.